# How to set the old .qgs file as the default project format in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I see [this discussion](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Why-is-qgz-the-default-format-td5392345i20.html) that one can change the default QGIS project format back to the text based `.qgs`. But there is no detail. Quoting the discussion:

> There is an option to start QGIS with another default setting file
>
> --globalsettingsfile
>
> https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#running-qgis-with-advanced-settings
>
> You can have a look at how the french ministry of ecology handles this
>   issue here:
>   http://www.geoinformations.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/qgis-package-3-4-2-pour-test-a3662.html

But the linked page does not mention .qgs.

*Does any one have a complete answer on how to change QGIS 3 default to use the old `.qgs` format?*

(as of QGIS 3.12, Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the changelog of [QGIS 3.12](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/index.html#id8), there is an option to change the default QGIS project to `.qgs`:

[image]

Check the above image, it is located at the bottom of General tab.